# Upgrade 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS fails

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 10.04

I have a test mail server that I tried to upgrade from 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS that failed at update-initramfs. It left the test system totally broken.

Initial kernel version: 2.6.32-52 x64

- 1 - execute: `apt-get update` to update sources. I have nothing unusual installed via apt-get, I did have Zimbra mail installed, it has it's own installer.
- 2 - do-release-upgrade

I did not upgrade to the latest package versions using `apt-get upgrade` nor latest kernel version `apt-get dist-upgrade`. I'm just wondering if that was the problem. I tested upgrades again with 10.04 virtualized (Citrix Xen) and was unable to duplicate an error.

I need to upgrade 3 production mail servers all running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (2.6.32-46-server) without crashing. Any suggestion upgrading I'd appreciate. I can't have this happen on a production box.

[image: Screen picture of crash]

Comment: Is updating directly from a installer disk a possibility? - also have you tried [reporting a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)? N.B. probably not [off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) , 10.04 server is [still supported until April 2015](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). And is this test server freshly installed, with no updates?

Comment: I haven't reported a bug. I could kick myself for not saving the logs. Spent a lot of time looking to see if anyone else ran into this issue. The installation did have updates after the initial installation, nothing after that.